# Is there an engine which can give a breakdown of its evaluations

Tags: engines

Engines evaluate a position based on a number of factors - material imbalance, king safety, control of the center, pawn structure etc.
My understanding is that they then combine these separate evaluations using a weighting for each (which can be adjusted), to produce a final score for the position.

Is there an engine which can display a breakdown of the separate evaluations?

For example:

Material: 0.00
King safety: -1.21
Center control: +0.87

Which means that material is equal, but black's king is less safe than whites, and white has better control of the center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Look at Stockfish 6. You can try it yourself.

EDITED

MG -> Middle Game
EG -> End Game

Most chess engines have a different set of evaluation or algorithm for an endgame. They could use it to model phase transition (e.g.: middle-game to end-game).

[image]

Comment: That's confusing, what do MG and EG mean? Why are the white and black columns equal?

Comment: See my edited....

Comment: They're equal because the initial position is symmetry. Anything that black has is also something white has. Overall, the balance of the position is equal.

Comment: Also, how do you get that analysis? Which commands do you have to run?

Answer (score 0):

Toga Log also gives a breakdown of its evaluations.